# PHP: Howto get sub_strings by regexp

Tags: php, regex

I have htacess rule like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)?$ index.php?tt=$1&ii=$2&ll=$3
```

Is there any PHP function that can do the same ?
Something like:

```
$A = XXXX_preg_match("([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)" , "A123-boooooo");
// $A become to =array("A","123","boooooo")
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match('/([a-zA-Z])(\d+)-([^\/]+)/', 'A123-boooooo', $A);
array_shift($A);
```

**Output:** `print_r($A);`

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => 123
    [2] => boooooo
)
```

Comment: You are missing the anchors from the original regex.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to retrieve those three values, you can pass an out-parameter to `preg_match` like this:

```
preg_match(
    '~^([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)$~' ,
    'A123-boooooo',
    $matches
);

$fullMatch = $matches[0]; // 'A123-boooooo'
$letter = $matches[1];    // 'A'
$number = $matches[2];    // '123'
$word = $matches[3];      // 'boooooo'

// Therefore
$A = array_slice($matches, 1);
```

If you want to do the replacement right away, use `preg_replace`:

```
$newString = preg_replace(
    '~^([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)$~',
    'index.php?tt=$1&ii=$2&ll=$3',
    'A123-boooooo
);
```

The [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pcre.php) of these is usually really good for further information.

Answer (score 0):

According to [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) doc

```
preg_match("~([A-z])([0-9]+)-([^/]*)~" , "A123-boooooo", $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

**output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => A123-boooooo
    [1] => A
    [2] => 123
    [3] => boooooo
)
```

Comment: You are missing the anchors from the original regex.